# jQuery: Check if date is inside multiple date ranges

Tags: jquery

I have an array with multiple date ranges. I need to check if a date is inside the ranges (checking for overlapping dates is not in scope right now.)

I have this code so far, but somehow it's not returning true even if today's date is within one of the date ranges.

```
// An array of objects containing date ranges
var datesArray = [{
  "from": "2/12/2016",
  "to": "8/12/2016",
  "schedule": 1
}, {
  "from": "11/10/2017",
  "to": "16/10/2017",
  "schedule": 2
}, {
  "from": "17/10/2017",
  "to": "22/10/2017",
  "schedule": 3
}];

// Today's date
var d = new Date();
var dd = d.getDate();
var mm = d.getMonth() + 1;
var yyyy = d.getFullYear();
var today = dd + "/" + mm + "/" + yyyy;
console.log("Today: " + today);

// For each calendar date, check if it is within a range.
for (i = 0; i < datesArray.length; i++) {
  // Get each from/to ranges
  var From = datesArray[i].from.split("/");
  var To = datesArray[i].to.split("/");
  // Format them as dates : Year, Month (zero-based), Date
  var FromDate = new Date(From[2], From[1] - 1, From[0]);
  var ToDate = new Date(To[2], To[1] - 1, To[0]);
  var schedule = datesArray[i].schedule;

  // Set a flag to be used when found
  var found = false;
  // Compare date
  if (today >= FromDate && today <= ToDate) {
    found = true;
    console.log("Found: " + schedule);
  }
}

//At the end of the for loop, if the date wasn't found, return true.
if (!found) {
  console.log("Not found");
}
```

[JsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/2udkLen1/).

What am I missing here?
Thanks.

Comment: `today` is not a date object. `d` is. Try comparing that?

Comment: ^ very good point.  multiple issues here.

Comment: @rybo111, that helped fix my problem. Could you provide an answer instead of a comment, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `today` is a string, whereas `d` is a `Date()`. You would benefit from more descriptive variable names, such as `todayString` and `todayDate`.

Also, I'm not sure if "today" is descriptive, as you are doing `+1` on `getMonth()`.

If your `datesArray` is determined in JavaScript, you could store `Date()` objects in there instead, but perhaps you did this for example purposes.

Answer (score 0):

What @Taplar said, simple fix:

```
var found = false
// For each calendar date, check if it is within a range.
for (i = 0; i < datesArray.length; i++) {
 .....

  // Compare date
  if (today >= FromDate && today <= ToDate) {
    found = true;
    console.log("Found: " + schedule);
    break; //stop looping.
  }
}

//At the end of the for loop, if the date wasn't found, return true.
if (!found) {
  console.log("Not found");
}
```